# Calendar Multiple URL's Output Specific Block/Menu Dead Links

Tags: datetime

Hi I've created a block that I only want to appear in the members area this includes a page where I use the Calendar Module, the problem I have is that I have listed the pages where the block should be outputted however with the calendar there are multiple url's for every view depending on month, so I can't feasibly output the block with all of these pages/url's which are possible through the calendar......

So is there a way to output this block specifically for every view output of the calendar, aside from listing all the url's in the block configuration page......

Also another issue the menu of the calendar isn't working, is there some setting I need to turn on in the admin area to get the menu to work........

http://www.cambrianvacation.co.uk/artbelow/?q=calendar-created/month

Regards

Ant

Answer (score 0):

Block visibility settings accept wildcard characters. If the calendar URL's are of the form, say:

```
/calendar/april/....
/calendar/may/....
```

all you have to do is to enter `calendar/*` in the block visibility settings, and all the pages will be identified. (Adjust according to the actual path of your calendar.)